# Cometd additional info during handshake

Tags: handshake, cometd

My app uses JWT for auth. The app is react on the frontend and spring on the backend. Recently i added push functionality using cometd, 7.0.10, and am running into an issue. As part of the cometd handshake and i send the jwt token, like so

```
var additional = {
    "com.app.credentials": {
        "token": localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
};
cometd.handshake(additional, function(handshakeReply) {
    if (handshakeReply.successful) {
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that the token is taken from localstorage when the page is first loaded - at that time the token is valid and there is no issue - the token is received by the server and the appropriate security checks are done (related to cometd).
However, the token is refreshed periodically, and after that happens **if** there happens to be a cometd handshake, then the token sent is the old one (set during 1st page load) - the correct one is available in localstorage. Since its the old one, the server side rejects it. Note this only affects cometd - the REST API's called by the JS to springboot all works well. If i reload the page then there is no issue - but i dont want to do that.

If the 'additional' param passed into cometd.handshake was a function that was invoked everytime cometd needed the additional params then it would solve my issue.

I am also assuming that one can invoke cometd.handshake only once.

Anyone help on how to resolve this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the 'additional' param passed into cometd.handshake was a function that was invoked everytime cometd needed the additional params then it would solve my issue.

Indeed.

```js
const additional = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return {
    "com.app.credentials": {
      "token": token
    }
  }
}

cometd.handshake(additional(), handshakeReply => {
  if (handshakeReply.successful) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Basically, you want to make `additional` a function that when invoked performs the lookup of the token in `localStorage`, so that it always retrieves the latest value.

Comment: Yes that would be perfect I think

Comment: I made changes in cometd.js and validated that it works. I commented out the first few lines of _handshake, which checks if the 1st argument is a function. I then changed the line that invokes the _mixin and there instead of passing the _handshakeProps, i first check if its a function - if so, its invoked, else the object is just passed in. Obviously the part i comment out is needed for backward compatibility - now to find a way to get this into the codebase. Not sure how to take this forward.
i cant seem to format code  - else i would have added it here

Comment: But you don't need to do any of what you described in the above comment! Just see my response; you can do everything from the application code without modifying `cometd.js`, which would be bad every time you update CoemtD to a new version.

Comment: Thanks so much - yes it works perfectly with no code change in cometd.